# 3rd party scripts on AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

I'm building out some amp pages as a working prototype, but need to include a script from Bizible, for tracing, and another script from Onetrust for cookie consent.

What is the best method to include 3rd part JavaScript in the HEAD? Would amp-script work for this?

Comment: You should read the AMP documentation, and specifically https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/

Comment: Which I have, and doesn't answer my question, which why I posted here. But thanks!

Comment: The amp-page  **does** answer the question - only amp-JS is allowed in HEAD!